# BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream); causes "Component cannot be found" exception

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on a UWP application where this CameraHelper class which stores the captured image from webcam with the line:

```
MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateBmp(), img);
```

Where img is previously declared as img = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();.

Now, since I also need to store this into a database, I need it converted into byte array - I do this with:

```
bytearray = new byte[img.Size];
await img.ReadAsync(bytearray.AsBuffer(), (uint) img.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

Now, later in the code, I try to convert this bytearray back to InMemoryRandomAccessStream with:

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await randomAccessStream.WriteAsync(img.AsBuffer());
randomAccessStream.Seek(0);
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);
```

The last line causes the exception from the title of the question! Any ideas? I am certain that the InMemoryRandomAccessStream is fine since I can actually convert it to SoftwareBitmapSource and I am seeing the image on the screen properly.

Comment: Can you tell what you are trying to achieve? If `img` is as a *Straem*, why not use just simply `BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(img);`?

Comment: I'm trying to store the image that img holds into a database, which means I need to convert it to a byte array and later (when retrieved from the db) reconvert it back to InMemoryRandomAccessStream so I can display it as a bitmap.

Comment: So the second part is just for reading the image back from the database. Have you taken a look [at this post](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-image-in-a-windows-store-app/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you can add `img.Seek(0);` before you convert the stream to byte array.

If you check the [`Position` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.position.aspx) of your `img` after calling `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` method, you will find its value is not `0`.
[image]

The `Position` is the byte offset of the stream. If we don't set it to zero, we will get a wrong byte array which can not be converted back to the original stream. And when we use the wrong stream in `BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync` method, we will get the exception.

So you can use some code like following to get the byte array:

```
MediaCapture captureManager = new MediaCapture();

InMemoryRandomAccessStream img = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
...

await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.CreateBmp(),
img);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(img.Position);
img.Seek(0);

var bytearray = new byte[img.Size];
await img.ReadAsync(bytearray.AsBuffer(), (uint)img.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

And then you can convert it back like:

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await randomAccessStream.WriteAsync(bytearray.AsBuffer());
```